# How to write PNG in rasterio from a stacked RGB?

Tags: python, rasterio

I have 3 variables namely R, G, B. I want to make a PNG image based on the three using rasterio. I tried using np.dstack to stack the 3 images and use the result to write it.

Using rasterio, I tried to write it this way:

```
rgb = np.dstack((Nr,Ng,Nb))  
finame = "Image_RGB.png"
with rasterio.Env():
    with rasterio.open(finame, 'w',
        driver='PNG',
        height=rgb.shape[0],
        width=rgb.shape[1],
        count=1,
        dtype=rgb.dtype,
        nodata=0,
        compress='deflate') as dst:
        dst.write(rgb, 1)
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: Source shape (1, 830, 793, 3) is inconsistent 
with given indexes 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Two things are going wrong here:

1. Rasterio is channels first, while you have channels last. In other words, the shape of the `rgb` should be (3, 830, 793) not (830, 793, 3).
2. You set `count=1` and do `dst.write(rgb, 1)`. This makes it try to write the rgb as the first band of the output file. Instead you want `count=3` and `dst.write(rgb)`.

This is a bit late for you, but maybe others will still be helped by my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Arthur's answer and the original code, this is one solution for this issue , the last row should be:

```
        dst.write(np.rollaxis(rgb, 2,0))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).